# In Asp.Net, what control is more suitable for getting time (hh:mm) from user and pass it as a parameter?

Tags: asp.net, time

In Asp.Net, what control is more suitable for getting time (hh:mm) from user and pass it as a parameter to a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit, you can use the [MaskedEdit control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx). The second example shows you how to let users enter a time-value.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to choose between the following three:

1. Use a `TextBox` and do extensive input validation.
2. Use solution #1, but add a [client side time picker](http://www.google.dk/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=jquery+time+picker&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) on top of the `TextBox`.
3. Use two `DropDownList` controls - one for hours, one for minutes.
4. Use some kind of third-party [time picker control](http://www.google.dk/search?hl=da&client=opera&rls=en&hs=cA2&q=timepicker+asp.net&btnG=S%C3%B8g&meta=&aq=f&oq=).

Which one is better? I would say, that depends a lot on the expected users of your application. Anyone used to working with a keyboard is likely to prefer the `TextBox`. Others might prefer the other options. For the broad masses, I would most likely go for solution #2, as it should suit both keyboard and mouse centric users.

If you choose to go with a third-party control, be wary that it might not degrade gracefully for users that do not accept Javascript. The control might just revert to a simple `TextBox`, possibly without any validation logic.